# How to decline a job opportunity politely through phone interview?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, careers

Currently I am an experienced developer who is looking for a job change. 
I got calls from companies after I updated my resume in job portals.

I got a call from a company stating that they are recruiting for their company. I also attended a telephonic interview for the job. They also told me that one more interview will be taken through phone by another person.

I searched through internet for company's profile. Company's profile is not looking good. They told that the work location is in my local while interviewing. But that place is not given in the website at all.

I read some of the reviews about the company by previous employees. 
The reviews are  not good (For example, Salary not provided on time, not having a good work culture etc).

It seems to be so suspicious about the company.

So I decided to decline this job offer. How to decline the job offer politely if they are going to offer the job?

**Update:**
I communicating through Phone and mail till now. I haven't met them directly.

Comment: Have you actually been on site yet? Or just the telephone interview and looking at web sites? I'd expect you'll at least be invited on site before they give you an offer.

Comment: But why would you even consider a job offer from a company whose profile is no good, has bad reviews, seems suspicious and has no location?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Decline the job offer?  You don't have a job offer.  Why would you continue to interview for a possible job offer if you don't plan on accepting.  They told you one more interview will be taken.  Simply decline the the interview.  "Sorry I decided not to pursue this opportunity."

Answer (score 3):

You can either be frank and tell them that you are not interested in the opportunity, by telling them the actual reasons that you didn't like the culture. It can come as harsh to the manager of the company, but would help them correct themselves.

Else, you can tell them that there is another opportunity which you have decided to pursue, and are no longer looking out for more. And thank them for their time.

Comment: mmmh, being frank with people you're unsure of is usually a bad move. they'll just hear that you're mistreating them, and it might haunt you back. Better thank them for their time

Answer (score -2):

You need to decide if you want to be honest (and possibly burn bridges / anger some people) or be polite (and not tell them why).

You can either:

a) Tell them frankly why you're not interested, and back up your claims (cite the website, the internet reviews, the disparity in their claims). Depending on the mood and the personality of the person you speak with you might burn some bridges. But you also might give them valueable feedback as to what to change.

b) Tell them you accepted another opportunity and thank them for their time. This is the easy, non-comittal, non-specific way out. That way you won't burn and bridges and won't anger people, but you also leave them none the wiser as to why you didn't want to work there.

Comment: You don't need to tell them anything specific, and probably shouldn't.  "Sorry, I don't feel this opportunity is right for me at this time" is enough, and is not going to burn any bridges.